# What's wrong in this SHA-256 Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, hash, passwords, sha, cryptojs

```
var secure;
var authentic;
secure = prompt("Enter password","");
alert(secure);

var c1 = CryptoJS.SHA256(secure);
alert(c1);


authentic = prompt("Enter password","");
alert(authentic);
var c2=CryptoJS.SHA256(authentic);
alert(c2);

if(c1==c2)
{
    alert("hi");
}
else
{
    alert("bye");
}
```

I use the script "http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/sha256.js"

EXPLANATION: What, I'm trying to do is to compare hashed passwords.If both the passwords entered (secure and authentic) that have been hashed (c1 and c2 respectively) are equal, It must display 'hi' to me. But I find that it displays 'bye' to me always.

PROBLEM: When I compare c1 and c2, the result I get always is 'bye', though the values of c1 and c2 are the same when I display them using the alert box.

I'm kinda new to hashing. A li'l help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You are doing a bad compare, you need a 'time constant' string compare to prevent timing attacks

Comment: @RichieFrame Difficult to say since the whole thing makes no sense at all. Unsalted SHA-2, comparison on the client, I don't even know where to start...

Comment: Use proper indentation.

Comment: I am trying to store data in client's web browser, so later if they wanna access it, they'll have to give the password!

Comment: If you are using a password to generate a cryptographic key, you need to be using a password based key derivation function, not a hash, and at that point you do not compare the key to a known key, you use it to attempt decryption

Comment: Well I use this hashed password to decrypt and encrypt the data. This is only the initial level entry though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/):

> The hash you get back isn't a string yet. It's a WordArray object. When you use a WordArray object in a string context, it's automatically converted to a hex string.

When you compare objects in JavaScript you are testing to see if they are the *same* object, not if they are identical objects.

Since you have created two WordArrays, you are comparing two different (but probably identical) objects.

You need to convert them to strings.

```
if ( (''+c1) == (''+c2) )
```

or

```
if ( c1.toString() == c2.toString() )
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much, Sir! I'm sorry I am not able to upvote coz I have less reputation.